# Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated error with php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx

I am getting `Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in <b>Unknown</b> on line`

I set always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 in my loaded php.ini but still it is throwing error. I am using nginx with php-fpm

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct `php.ini` the FPM one may be different than the default one

Comment: You need to restart the fpm container.

Comment: How I can find php.ini using by FPM? @arkascha - I restarted fpm using the command "brew services restart php56" but still it's showing the error.

Comment: Execute `phpinfo()` once, it tells which ini files it read.

Comment: yes I changed in the loaded php.ini file from phpinfo, but still it is showing always_populate_raw_post_data as 0 in phpinfo

Comment: I restarted my computer and now it is working thaks